# forcing a variable to hold certain values only

Tags: c#

I am using vs 2012. I have a simple string property

```
 string _someString;

 public string MyString
  {
     get
       {
          return _someString;
       }

   }
```

I want this property to hold only certain values. So that when the client uses this property only those certain values can be used.

Comment: You can only fix the type of a variable unless you want to do validation during set

Comment: Perhaps you should use an enum instead of a string.

Comment: use enum instead of string

Comment: You should use enum for such tasks.

Comment: If this is GET only property - just don't set `_someString` to values you don't want - user will not be able to change it anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you *really* want is an `enum`:

```
public enum MyValues //TODO rename all the things
{
    SomeValue,
    SomeOtherValue,
    FinalValue,
}
```

Then your property can be:

```
private MyValues value;
public  MyValues MyValue
{
    get { return value; }
}
```

If you need to get a string representation of that value just call `ToString` on the enum value:

```
string stringValue = value.ToString();
```

Comment: I should note that, unless I am mistaken, the "values" that we are working with here are always of type `int`.  So it should me noted that in this case, `MyValues.SomeValue.ToString()` will result in a `string` with value `"1"`, not the expected `"SomeValue"`

Comment: @JHixson That is false.  `Myfalse.SomeValue.ToString()` will result in `"SomeValue"`.  That is simply how enums defined their ToString method, even though the underlying value stored is an integer, byte, or whatever other numeric value.  You'd need to cast it to an `int` before calling `ToString` to get the string value of the numeric representation.

Answer (score 2):

Use an enum as in :

```
enum MyEnum
{
AllowableValue#1,
AllowableValue#2,
...
}

public MyEnum myEnum { get; set; }
```

Then populate some UI element with only the values of the enum.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to have some validation on the setter then:

```
public string MyString
{
    get
    {
        return _someString;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == "a" || value == "b" /* ... */)
            _someString = value;
        else
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid value!");
    }
}
```

Make sure to set it via the property, not the actual member variable.